# What's the difference between ggplot and basic plot in R?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

For plotting graphs in R, I usually use basic plot `plot()`, `barplot()`, `boxplot()`... functions from the package `graphics`. But `ggplot` seemed to be used more often.

What are the main differences between the two types of graphics to take into account when choosing which one to use ?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The base plotting paradigm is "ink on paper" whereas the `lattice` and `ggplot` paradigms are basically writing a program that uses the `grid`-package to accomplish the low-level output to the target graphics devices. (See `?Devices`) The author of the `grid` package has written an excellent book, "R Graphics". (See `help(pac=grid)` ) The `ggplot`-paradigm has the "Grammar of Graphics" inspiration and tries to integrate a variety of different plotting functions into one logically coherent package. It does require loading the `ggplot2` package, whereas R starts up with the `graphics` and `grDevices` packages already loaded. Both `ggplot2` and `lattice` functions require the use of an explicit `print` call when they are used inside a function.

With `ggplot2` you assign the result of that function to an object name and then further modify it. When it's ready for "publication" you get the output processed and sent to a device with `print`. "ggplot" graphics often get progressively modified by adding "layers" to a base plot created with `qplot` or `ggplot` through the use of the `+.gg`-function. See `` ?ggplot2::`+.gg` ``  (For many years ggplot2's help pages would refer you to `?layer` but when you got there the was basically empty. They fixed that ... after about a decade.)

In the case of `base`-graphics there is no R object that holds results. The commands get processed immediately and inscribed on the "paper" of the current device. You then issue further commands to augment the output on that device. The `plotrix` package gives a good example of the development of advanced plotting facilities using the `base`-graphics paradigm.

One major limitation of `ggplot2`-functions versus `base` and `lattice` graphics functions is that ggplot2 does not have any 3D plotting functions. The `lattice`-package, however, is not being actively maintained, but it seemed fairly mature at the point that active development was stopped and if you find a bug it will probably be fixed. There are both the `gridExtra` and `latticeExtra` packages that extend lattice and ggplot2 capabilities. There is now also a `gridBase` package that supports saving base plotting results as a grid "grob" and then merging base and grid, i.e. `lattice` or `ggplot`, output.  It is certainly true that "ggplot"-paradigm seems to be the target of more sustained activity in recent years.

Comment: It would not be harmful to mention that `lattice` and `ggplot2` are extensions of the `grid` graphics engine, which represent a separate exposure to objects relative to the base graphics engine.

Comment: My first sentence kind did that. ... I thought.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation !

Comment: @IRTFM You answered the question. Why not vote to open the question? I see no point of closing it. The reason to close it makes no sense, given a legitimate answer is already given.